# How to throw a StackOverflowException

Tags: java, arrays, try-catch, overriding

I am currently making a Bounded Array Stack. this method throws arrays that are larger then the storage capacity to the `StackOverflowException`, except i keep getting an error message for the "`throws StackOverflowException` part

```
public void push(T item) throws StackOverflowException {
    //push item onto the stack,
    if (isFull()) throw new StackOverflowException();
    else {
        top++;
        storage[top] = item;
    }
}
```

Error Message:

> Error:(52, 17) java: `push(T)` in `com.ld.BoundedArrayStack` cannot
>   implement `push(T)` in `com.ld.StackADT`  overridden method does not throw
>   `com.ld.StackOverflowException`

other message:

> `push(T)` in `com.Id.BoundedArrayStack` clashes with `push(T)` in
>   `com.Id.StackADT`; overridden method does not throw
>   `com.Id.StackOverflowException`

i dont understand what the problem is.

Comment: Well, you can't override method and add to it new non-runtime exception (which I believe `com.ld.StackOverflowException` is). How would client using supertype reference be aware of this new exception and handle it properly?

Comment: Is it a method of a subclass? Does the superclass' method throw that exception? Do you have access to the superclass' source?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your error message, your superclass `StackADT` defined `push` not to throw `StackOverflowException`, so any override of this method cannot throw `StackOverflowException` either.

You can either:

- Make your `StackOverflowException` a `RuntimeException`, which can always be thrown at any time.  You don't have to declare it in the `throws` clause, or
- Declare the `push` method in `StackADT` so that it `throws` a `StackOverflowException`.